# Pyinstaller No module named msvc

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using Pyinstaller on Ubuntu to create a binary executable for my Python code. This code has a bunch of files and dependencies. One of them is `tensorflow`. The executable is getting created correctly but when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detection_init.py", line 14, in <module>
    import lib.tensorboxDetector as tensorboxDetector
  File "/tmp/pip-build-EuLWEf/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "lib/tensorboxDetector.py", line 20, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/tmp/pip-build-EuLWEf/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-EuLWEf/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 104, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-EuLWEf/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "tensorflow/python/platform/test.py", line 57, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-EuLWEf/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "mock/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-EuLWEf/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "mock/mock.py", line 71, in <module>
  File "pbr/version.py", line 461, in semantic_version
  File "pbr/version.py", line 447, in _get_version_from_pkg_resources
  File "/tmp/pip-build-EuLWEf/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "pbr/packaging.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-EuLWEf/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "setuptools/__init__.py", line 160, in <module>
  File "setuptools/monkey.py", line 104, in patch_all
  File "setuptools/monkey.py", line 156, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
  File "importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
ImportError: No module named msvc
```

How can I resolve this error and run the file correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by using the dev version of Pyinstaller. More details here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2824

Answer (score 0):

I added `msvc` to the hidden imports. I'm still battling imports, but seem to be past this one.

```py
{
    a = Analysis(['/Users/Ben/Documents/DeepMeerkat/DeepMeerkat/main.py'],
                 pathex=['/Users/ben/Documents/DeepMeerkat/DeepMeerkat/'],
                 binaries=[],
                 datas=[],
                 hiddenimports=['setuptools.msvc'],
                 hookspath=[],
                 runtime_hooks=[],
                 excludes=[ 'enchant', 'twisted'],
                 win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
                 win_private_assemblies=False,
                 cipher=block_cipher)
}
```

Comment: You can try using dev version. It solved the problem for me.

Comment: so, git clone the dev branch and python setup.py install

Comment: Install directly with `pip` `pip install -e https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip`